# Polymorphic EJB client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I am using EJB 3.1 and jersey for a restapi. I would like to have a `SuperResource` as below, which is then inherited by the actual rest resources as below. The way I have it now, my `@EJB` object is null. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
@Stateless
public class SuperResource {
    @EJB
    protected GenericDao<DomainObject> dao;
    . . .
}


public class MyResource extends SuperResource{     
    public String doGet(){
       return dao.get(...);
   }
}
```

I have tried the whole truth table between `@Stateless` and `@Local`, and `SuperResource` and `MyResource`. None of the permutations seems to work.

I don't know if that's important, my server is Glassfish 3.1.2

EDIT TO ADD DETAILS:

I didn't think so , but it seems that more detail may be necessary here:

Structure of my application:

```
@Local
public interface GenericDao<T extends DomainObject> {…}

public interface LoginDao  extends GenericDao<Login>{...}

@Stateless
public class GenericDaoImpl<T extends DomainObject> implements GenericDao<T> {…}

@Stateless
public class LoginDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Login> implements LoginDao {…}

@Entity
public class Login implements java.io.Serializable, DomainObject {…}
```

What works:

```
@Stateless
@Path("mypath")
public class MyResource{   
@EJB
private LoginDao dao;  
  public String doGet(){
    return dao.get(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the @Stateless annotation from SuperResource to MyResource.

Answer (score 0):

`MyResource` has to be an EJB bean as well, by annotating it with `@Stateless`:

```
@Stateless
public class MyResource extends SuperResource{     
    public String doGet(){
       return dao.get(...);
   }
}
```

If you only need the injected DAO, you could choose to inject your JAX-RS resource with that DAO using CDI instead. If you resources -becomes- a stateless bean, then this has certain consequences that you need to be aware of (like a transaction that starts for every method, unless you explicitly disable that, etc).

Comment: I have edited above to add details (not sure if they are necessary). I am also adding (as comment) the error I get after doing what you suggested.

Comment: SEVERE: EJB5070: Exception creating stateless session bean : [GenericDaoImpl]
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB GenericDaoImpl, method: public void ccv4.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.save(ccv4.domain.utils.DomainObject)
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:454)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2547)

Comment: at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1899)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)

Comment: My knowledge of CDI is limited to pretty much what I have in my post. Do you mind editing your post to show an example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EJB injection issue. Depending on Server, you need to play around mappedName/name/beanName

What I can confirm is that, the following code works on JBoss 7.1.1.

```
        @Local
        public interface HelloWorldLocal {
            public String sayHello();
        }

        @Stateless
        public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldLocal {
            public String sayHello(){
                return "Hello..............................................................................";
            }
        }

        @Remote
        public interface BaseRemote {
            public String test();
        }

        @Stateless
        public class BaseBean implements BaseRemote{
            @EJB
            HelloWorldLocal bean;
            public String test() {
                return "Base Bean";
            }
        }

        @Remote
        public interface DerivedRemote {
            String test();
        }

        @Stateful
        public class DerivedBean extends BaseBean implements DerivedRemote{
            public String test() {
                return bean.sayHello();
            }
        }
```